# How to make a button Work within a fragment (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, button

I Have an activity fragment whereby i have it call out values from a separate data class and also a .xml file

I want the button in the .xml file to be accessible in the Kotlin CLASS.however, an error keeps showing that the declared function is unreachable.
What i have done:

the kotlin class page:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

private val personcolletionref =Firebase.firestore.collection( "users")

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

    submitbutton.setOnClickListener {

    }

}
private fun savePerson (person: Person) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    try {
        personcolletionref.add(person).await()
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }catch (e: Exception) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

}

the button in the xml file to be called:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="268dp"
        android:text="Submit"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/edittextage"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/edittextage" />
```

Comment: What does "an error keeps showing that the declared function is unreachable" mean?  What is the error?

Answer (score 2):

In the onCreateView method, you just have to return the view. Override the following method and write your button on click listener init

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
       submitbutton.setOnClickListener {

         }
    }
```

Comment: its still not working,, dont know if i should show you a screenshot